# Dynamic user home directory on Windows (changing %HOMEDRIVE% and %HOMEPATH%)

Tags: windows, cmd, environment-variables, portability, home-directory

### Actual question

How can I "redirect" (symbolic links?) or temporarily change the values of `%HOMEDRIVE%` and `%HOMEPATH%` (maybe based on two batch scripts that change the values when I start working at the machine and reset everything after I'm done)?

### Background

A lot of Windows programs pick up either system variable `%USERPROFILE%` or a combination of `%HOMEDRIVE%` and `%HOMEPATH` in order to figure out where a user's "home" directory is that they need to use (e.g. `C:\Users\JohnDoe`). Being a fan of the philosophy of *portable apps* (see at the bottom what I mean by that), I'm wondering if I could somehow make my home directory portable, i.e. have it point to a directory on a portable device. Or, in other words, I would like to make it "dynamically changeable".

### What I tried

I've read a bit about [`Set`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) and [`Setx`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104.aspx) and tried this:

Finding out what the current variable values are:

```
C:\Users\JohnDoe> Set HOME
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\<username>
```

Set them:

```
C:\Users\JohnDoe> Setx HOMEDRIVE "d:"
C:\Users\JohnDoe> Setx HOMEPATH "\home"
```

That creates `HOMEDIR` and `HOMEPATH` as user-specific environment variables (see Control Panel >> System >> Environment Variables). But the "global ones" did not change and e.g. RStudio will not recognize the user-specific variables (still writes to `C:\Users\JohnDoes\[...]`).

```
C:\Users\JohnDoe> Set HOME
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\<username>
```

---

### Portable Apps

For example, see PortableApps.com or simply think "software that simply has been installed to a portable device instead of `C:\Program Files\<app-name>`". The latter works a treat for me for programs that don't really care about `%HOMEDRIVE%` and `%HOMEPATH%` (e.g. [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/) or [R](http://www.r-project.org/)).

Some others (e.g. [Git](http://git-scm.com/)) just need to be tweaked a little bit (e.g. see [this post](http://danlimerick.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/git-for-windows-tip-setting-home-and-the-startup-directory/)).

Yet some others (e.g. [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/)) run in fact smoothly off the portable device, but write stuff to the user's "home" directory. That's the kind of software that I would like to tell to use a directory on my portable device instead.

Comment: You can just use `set` to change the environment variables for the current command shell and launch the application from that shell.  But of course that only works if the application actually looks at the environment variables (which it should't, but some do).

Comment: Okay, thanks! That might at least be an option.

Answer (score 1):

While you can change the environment variables this wont work for all applications, as there is also a Shell folder API in Windows which gives various user specific locations.

So it is better to use the actual Windows method to change the profile. And no this will not be possible to be a mobile device as it expects a stable and available location for the registry database of the user.

I think when setting up windows (and with sysprep) one can specify a location for the }users} folder (different drive). The quickest thing to move are the special library folders, you can change their location in the Explorer Properties view.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying that! You mentioned some things that I'm not familiar yet, though: how would I change a profile and what special library folders are you referring to?